# Spring Data PagedListHolder is not returning correct PageSize when size input is set greater than 15 for List Pagination,why?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to achieve pagination for List data with `PagedListHolder` from Spring but when set input size greater than 15 ,its now returning expected output.

```java
private List<WorklistResponse> getPaginatedResponseResult(List<WorklistResponse> worklistResponse, FilterRequest filterRequest) {
    PagedListHolder<WorklistResponse> pagedListHolder = new PagedListHolder<WorklistResponse>();

    pagedListHolder.setSource(worklistResponse);
    pagedListHolder.setPage(filterRequest.getCurrentPage());// 1
    pagedListHolder.setPageSize(filterRequest.getPageSize());// 29

    System.out.println(worklistResponse.size());//total input list size 30
    System.out.println(pagedListHolder.getPageSize());  // after setting size 29
    System.out.println(pagedListHolder.getPageList().size());// actual page element size result is 1 which is not correct ,it should be 29

    return pagedListHolder.getPageList();
}
```

In class `PagedListHolder`, below methods is impacting on result:

```java
public List<E> getPageList() {
    return this.getSource().subList(this.getFirstElementOnPage(), this.getLastElementOnPage() + 1);
}
```

How I can get correct page size for any input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have 30 records, page 1 and page size 29 returns 1 record because:** [`PagedListHolder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/support/PagedListHolder.html) is a simple state holder for handling lists of objects, separating them into pages. Page numbering starts with 0.

**If structurally your first page is 1**, then subtract 1 when submitting the page number. e.g:

```java
pagedListHolder.setPage(filterRequest.getCurrentPage() - 1);
```